# use facebook data in yii

Tags: javascript, php, api

i am trying to get data from a user that register facebook using yii framework and i dont know why i want and i have fetched it but i want to know how to get each data from the `facebook.js` class and place it in a hidden type in the `influenza_info.php` class. how do i get the data from the `facebook.js` class

this is my `facebook.js` class

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '************',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function getInfo() {
  FB.login(function(){
      // Note: The call will only work if you accept the permission request
      FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name, first_name, picture, email, friends, birthday, age_range, location'}, function(response) {
          console.log(response);
                  $('fb_firstname').val(response.first_name);
        });
    }, {scope: ''});
  }
```

this is my `influenza_info.php` class

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
$module = $this->context->module;
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl. '/js/facebook.js');

$this->title = Yii::t('user', 'Influenza Information', ['position' => $this::POS_BEGIN]);

$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>

<div class="container">
 <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php if ($flash = Yii::$app->session->getFlash("Register-success")): ?>
<div class="alert alert-success">
<p><?= $flash ?></p>
</div>
 <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([

        'id' => "example-advanced-form",

    ]); ?>

    <h3>Finish</h3>

    <fieldset>
<legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>
<input id="acceptTerms-2" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> <label for="acceptTerms-2">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>

    </fieldset>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

i want to fetch the firstname from the js and put it in a label in `influenza_info.php` inside fieldset. how do i do it

Answer (score 0):

You have to store it somewhere.
For example, you could write the info you need to cookie, so you would be able to read from PHP:

js:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name, first_name, picture, email, friends, birthday, age_range, location'}, function(response) {
    document.cookie = "fbLastName=" + response.last_name;
});
```

php:

```
$form->input($model, 'last_name', ['value' => Yii::app()->request->cookies['fbLastName']->value]);
```

But it would be better to store user-related data in user model.

Comment: i have been trying your answer but their is still error i edited it a bit  this is how it looks   "<?= $form->field($model, 'last_name', ['value' => Yii::$app->request->cookies['fbLastName']->value])?>"      now i am getting this error .. 
   "Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ActiveField::value"

Comment: It's just a sketch, you have to correct syntax according to Yii

Comment: I assume it's something like this: `$form-> field($model, 'last_name', ['htmlOptions' => ['value' =>Yii::$app->request->cookies['fbLastName']->value]]);`

Comment: how can i just fetch and put it in normal html <label> tag .

Comment: If you've created this cookie at the moment you can output it like this: `<label for="field_name_goes_here"><?= Yii::$app->request->cookies['cookie_name_goes_here']->value ?> </label>`. Also Yii have a method for labels

Comment: That means the cookie wasn't set at this moment. Notice the JS is running after the PHP code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98961/discussion-between-arinze-and-switcher).